# error: unknown register name 'r3' in 'asm' , in clobber

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I want to write an inline assembly function which will do multiplication and shift then shift the result to a 32 bit value , I require clobbers for it but cannot use any , generating error

**I want to use clobbers for doing the calculation and then return the result**

```
    static inline int32_t multi(int32_t in0, int32_t in1)
{
    int32_t res=0;
    asm volatile ( "add.n r3 , %1 ,%1\n"
           "mull %0, %2 , r3\n"
           :"=r"(res) 
           : "r"(in0), "r"(in1)
               :"cc","r3");  
     return res;

}
```

It is producing following error ,

> error: unknown register name 'r3' in 'asm'

I have tried numerous registers like a1 a2 etc. but nothing seems to work , Am I doing some silly mistake in the code above

Comment: Which architecture are you programming for?

Comment: Note that the compiler is probably quite capable of generating arithmetic instructions from simple C code. Make sure it's not premature optimization.

Comment: I don't recognize the arch here, but I wonder if you could do something like: `"add.n %0 , %1 ,%1\n mull %0, %2 , %0\n"`?  Uses fewer registers, and no clobber required.

Comment: I was programming for xtensa , esp32 chip

Comment: This is just a basic code , I need to make it more complex but if I can't use clobbers it won't work,  @DavidWohlferd

Comment: I'm not find docs specifically for that, but some of the xtensa samples I've found use register names starting with 'a' (ie a3).  Failing that, try prefixing your 2 asm lines with comment markers, and compile with -S to see what assembler gets generated for %0, %1, etc.

Comment: Yeah, like @DavidWohlferd said I'd suggest looking at compiler-generated asm.  You just need it to compile, not assemble, so you actually just need to temporarily comment out the clobbers in the asm statement where the error about `r3` was coming from.  It doesn't matter what text is in the asm template for gcc; it's just a text substitution.  (Clang OTOH does care if the result assembles so asm comments inside the template string might be needed too.)

Comment: @DavidWohlferd , Thanks, It worked , I wrongly assumed the general name of the registers to be starting from r , but in xtensa it is actually starting from a "

Comment: Huh, well, there you go.  Just to wrap things up, I should mention that using inline asm (correctly) is really hard, and generally a [bad idea](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  Yes, it's powerful, yes it's educational, but almost always a bad idea for production code.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I figured it out today itself , when inline asm required more time than inline c function , Well just out of curiosity If I have a big function in c and I convert it into assembly in .S file would it boost the performance

Comment: "If I have a big function in c and I convert it into assembly in .S file would it boost the performance" - It would be precisely the same code, so the performance would be unchanged.  In theory it could serve as a starting point for you to edit and fine-tune it, but most people aren't good enough assembly programmers to be able to generate better asm than today's compilers.  Compiler writers have been tuning, optimizing, and learning all the tricks for decades.

Comment: Ok , Thanks !! , Can you suggest a good book for assembly programming !! , It seems very much interesting

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what's 'add.n'. But from the description, I guessed you probably want following:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"

static inline int32_t multi(int32_t in0, int32_t in1)
{
        asm volatile (  "mul %1 \t\n"
                        :"+a"(in0), "+c"(in1)
                        :
                        :"memory");
        return in0;

}

void main() {
        int32_t a, b;

        //test data
        a = 2;
        b = 7;

        printf("result: %d\n", multi(a,b));
}
```

Comment: Is this code for x86?  OP is using different hw (xtensa), which uses different [constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) (ie no `c`).

Comment: Even if this was for x86, it's unsafe: you correctly specify the input / low-half-output in `"+a"` (EAX), but you forgot to tell the compiler that 1-operand `mul` destroys EDX with the high half.  (1-operand `mul` is less efficient than `imul` and you shouldn't be using anyway if you don't want the high half.)  Also you don't need or want `volatile` or a `"memory"` clobber, and `in1` doesn't need to be in ECX.  It's also not modified so an input-only `"r"(in1)` would make more sense.  Or `"r,m"` to allow memory if you used `mull` for force the operand-size.